# CodeIgniter PHP - How to choose which ID to select in a join while using "select *"

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select, join

Basically, I've got this coding convention that any primary key which is an ID, I will call the column name "id". So here comes my problem. I'm joining two tables and I'm getting the ID of the second table instead of the first table. I know if I use select "artists.id, ..." it will work, but I want to know if there's a fix with using "select *" which would be better for future expansion (new colums will come ...).

Here's my model:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('artists');
$this->db->join('categories', 'artists.category_id = categories.id');
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->limit(1);
```

With Print_R I can see I'm getting all columns (but only 1 id, which is from the categories table instead of artists table) without any table prefix.

Comment: No. Avoid "SELECT *".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should qualify your columns with a table alias

```
$this->db->select('a.id as artist_id, c.id as category_id, a.column2,c.column3');
$this->db->from('artists a');
$this->db->join('categories c', 'a.category_id = c.categories.id');
$this->db->where('a.id', $id);
$this->db->limit(1);
```

If you want to continue using `SELECT *`

```
$this->db->select('a.*, c.*, a.id as artist_id, c.id as category_id');
$this->db->from('artists a');
$this->db->join('categories c', 'a.category_id = c.categories.id');
$this->db->where('a.id', $id);
$this->db->limit(1);
```

Keep in mind, that the LAST duplicate column will be returned.  So, `a.*,c.*` will return `c.id` as `id` and `c.*,a.*` will return `a.id` as `id`.

Comment: Beat me to it. Good answer

Comment: you can always edit my answer and add some links for reference ;)

Comment: Hmm well I knew that :D. I was wondering if there was a way to do it using "select *" :P. So I guess there is none?

Comment: @KevinVanRyckegem: Not with MySQL.

Comment: Alright thanks for the info! I know it's better not to use select *, but I'm always wondering if there are other ways of doing it that I don't know about :).

Comment: You should avoid `SELECT *` but an example of how to use it in your circumstance is now in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think to save you trouble and for the future, always use the table in front of the column name. 
There is no logic here, when you look for * it means all fields, in Oracle for example you will get all fields with the table in front, i guess in MySQL it doesn't, but if i were you, i  would not risk it.